# How to convert an integer fractional part to the correspondent binary fractional part in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, binary, numbers, x86-16, fractions

For example, on the paper if I have:

> 14.6875

in decimal notation, it's simple obtaining the binary notation's counterpart:

> 1101.1011

.

This because: `1*2^(3)+1*2^(2)+0*2^(1)+1*2^(0)+1*2^(-1)+0*2^(-2)+1*2^(-3)+1*2^(-4)`.

This it's all ok.

I can implement easily the conversion from a fractional binary part to the decimal notation. The problem is the reverse. If I have

> 0.4321

for example, how I do in assembly 8086 a procedure that converts only the fractional part:

> 4321

in binary notation?

I should to do this (more or less):

```
(Iteration) Multiplicand    Multiplier  Carry
0           0.432100        2           0
1           0.864200        2           0
2           1.728400        2           1
3           1.456800        2           1
4           0.913600        2           0
5           1.827200        2           1
6           1.654400        2           1
7           1.308800        2           1
8           0.617600        2           0
9           1.235200        2           1
10          0.470400        2           0
11          0.940800        2           0
12          1.881600        2           1
13          1.763200        2           1
14          1.526400        2           1
15          1.052800        2           1
16          0.105600        2           0
17          0.211200        2           0
18          0.422400        2           0
19          0.844800        2           0
20          1.689600        2           1
21          1.379200        2           1
22          0.758400        2           0
23          1.516800        2           1
24          1.033600        2           1
25          0.067200        2           0
26          0.134400        2           0
27          0.268800        2           0
28          0.537600        2           0
29          1.075200        2           1
30          0.150400        2           0
31          0.300800        2           0
32          0.601600        2           0
33          1.203200        2           1
34          0.406400        2           0
35          0.812799        2           0
36          1.625599        2           1
37          1.251198        2           1
38          0.502396        2           0
39          1.004791        2           1
40          0.009583        2           0
41          0.019165        2           0
42          0.038330        2           0
43          0.076660        2           0
44          0.153320        2           0
45          0.306641        2           0
46          0.613281        2           0
47          1.226562        2           1
48          0.453125        2           0
49          0.906250        2           0
50          1.812500        2           1
51          1.625000        2           1
52          1.250000        2           1
53          0.500000        2           0
54          1.000000        2           1
```

Considering the column of remainder in the same sense (in accord to the iterations) the fractional part in binary is:

- considering no limits in number of digits:

> 0.4321 <=> 0.0011011101001111000011011000010001001101000000010011101

- consider a fixed point notation (16 digits for bin, 4 digits for dec):

> 0.4321 <=> 0.0011011101001111[TRUNCATED WITH ROUNDING]
>   .

How I do all that in a very efficient way in FLAT 8086?

(I apologize to everyone for writing of bestiality previously.)

Comment: Your conversion is wrong. Obviously if the first bit after the binary point is `1` the fractional part is more than half, but `0.4321` is clearly less. (Looks like you used your original example of `1.6875` there). Anyway, a simple algorithm is check if it's more than `5000`. If it is, you have 1 bit and subtract `5000`, if it isn't, you have a `0` bit. Multiply by 2 and repeat.

Comment: Are you looking for something like you'd find as part of a general-purpose `strtod` library function?  http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/  Figure out which of those corner cases you need to handle.  You may need to look at more than 4 decimal digits to get 4 correctly-rounded binary digits.  (I forget, but you should read that post and check if I'm remembering that correctly.)  As usual, the algorithm is the same regardless of language.  Doing it asm just makes bit twiddling easier to express sometimes, e.g. shift sets CF = the last bit shifted out.

Comment: You can't convert 1.4321 from decimal to binary by converting 4321 from decimal to binary and then putting an one and period (`1.`) in front of it.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed implicitly that the conversion of the integer part was automatic, so for this reason I have not written in the example. The 1 is only an easy example, I need to convert the fractional part only.

Comment: I apologize to everyone for writing of bestiality previously, it's correct now?

Comment: You can check your calculation [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/) or google for "fractional binary online". Why don't you consider @Jester's comment?

Comment: @rkhb ok, I'm trying to do the Jester's comment! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here a possible solution, maybe it's not an elegant solution, I think that it could be improve a lot, but at least the basic concept seems to work:

```
;PROCEDURE EXPLANATION      
;This procedure converts the 4 digits of decimal fraction
;in to correspondent binary notation.   

;DATA STRUCTURE USED

;REGISTERS USED

;EXTERNAL REQUIREMENTS

;OUTPUT

.model small
.stack
.data

;EXAMPLE DATA
int_example dw  0
frac_example dw 1234        ;num is: 0.6425

;REQUIRED DATA

;OUTPUT DATA
int_out dw  ?
frac_out dw ?

.code
.startup

          mov ax, int_example
          mov bx, frac_example
          call convert


.exit

convert proc
    call int_b_conversion
    call frac_b_conversion

    ret
convert endp

int_b_conversion proc

    ;to do
    mov int_out, ax

    ret
int_b_conversion endp 

frac_b_conversion proc
    mov ax, 5000d
    xor dx, dx ;REG used to store the binary fractional part
    mov cx, 08d ;almost 8 digits in an half REG
    cyc_01:   
        rol dx, 1
        cmp bx, ax
        jg greater_so_sub
        je break
        ;lesser so multiply
        rol bx, 1 ;mul by 2
            ;have 0
        jmp dodge_01
        greater_so_sub:
            inc dx ;have 1
            sub bx, ax
            rol bx, 1
        dodge_01:
    loop cyc_01

    jmp dodge_02


    break:
        sub cx, 1
        inc dx
        cyc_02:    
            rol dx, 1
            loop cyc_02
    dodge_02:

    mov frac_out, dx 

    ret
frac_b_conversion endp

end
```

Answer (score 0):

An update here, with no constraints in number of decimal digits.

```
;PROCEDURE EXPLANATION      
;This procedure converts any digits (max 8) of a decimal fractional
;part in to correspondent binary notation.   
; In altre parole, questa funzione si occupa di convertire
; la parte frazionaria di un numero dalla notazione decimale
; a quella binaria.

;DATA STRUCTURE USED

;REGISTERS USED

;EXTERNAL REQUIREMENTS

;OUTPUT

.model small
.stack
.data

;EXAMPLE DATA
frac_example dw 654 ;num is: 0.1234
            ;i.e. the fractional part only

;REQUIRED DATA
some_number_010     dw      ?   ;This number, for example, requires
                                ;five digits to be represented in
                                ;the decimal notation. (INPUT)

number_of_digits_010        dw      ?       ;This is the OUTPUT of the
                                        ;procedure.
subtrahend_010 dw   ?

;OUTPUT DATA
frac_out dw ?

.code
.startup

          ;proc begin (argument passe by bx)
          mov bx, frac_example
          call frac_b_conversion
          ;proc end


.exit


frac_b_conversion proc 
    ;Nelle seguenti tre righe c'è l'algoritmo che serve per capire
    ;quante sono le cifre decimali del numero da convertire 
    ;e in base a questo valore assegna al sottraendo un valore pari a
    ; 5, 50, 500, 5000 o 50000
    mov some_number_010, bx
    call subtrahend_definition_010
    mov ax, subtrahend_010
    xor dx, dx ;REG used to store the binary fractional part
    mov cx, 08d ;almost 8 digits in an half REG
    cyc_01:   
        rol dx, 1
        cmp bx, ax
        jg greater_so_sub
        je break
        ;lesser so multiply
        rol bx, 1 ;mul by 2
            ;have 0
        jmp dodge_01
        greater_so_sub:
            inc dx ;have 1
            sub bx, ax
            rol bx, 1
        dodge_01:
    loop cyc_01

    jmp dodge_02


    break:
        sub cx, 1
        inc dx
        cyc_02:    
            rol dx, 1
            loop cyc_02
    dodge_02:

    mov frac_out, dx 

    ret
frac_b_conversion endp

subtrahend_definition_010        proc
        push ax
        push bx
        push dx

        mov ax, some_number_010
        mov bx, 9
        cmp ax, bx
        jg next_digit_count_1_010
        mov bx, 1       ;One digit.
        mov dx, 5
        mov subtrahend_010, dx
        jmp end_subtrahend_definition_010

next_digit_count_1_010:        
        mov bx, 99
        cmp ax, bx
        jg next_digit_count_2_010
        mov bx, 2       ;Two digit.
                mov dx, 50
        mov subtrahend_010, dx
        jmp end_subtrahend_definition_010

next_digit_count_2_010:        
        mov bx, 999
        cmp ax, bx
        jg next_digit_count_3_010
        mov bx, 3       ;Three digit.
                mov dx, 500
        mov subtrahend_010, dx
        jmp end_subtrahend_definition_010

next_digit_count_3_010:        
        mov bx, 9999
        cmp ax, bx
        jg next_digit_count_4_010
        mov bx, 4       ;Four digit.
                mov dx, 5000
        mov subtrahend_010, dx
        jmp end_subtrahend_definition_010

next_digit_count_4_010:        
        ;Five digit. (Last case: comparisons not needed).
        mov dx, 50000
        mov subtrahend_010, dx
        end_subtrahend_definition_010:
        pop dx
        pop bx
        pop ax      
        ret
subtrahend_definition_010        endp


end
```